# Loopback afterRemote of __get__identities not executed

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a user model which `hasMany` `userIdentity`, the relationship name is 'identities'.

I defined the following in `user` model. However, when I can `GET /users/me/identities`, it returns me the correct resource, but the afterRemote never get executed.

```
User.afterRemote('__get__identities', function (context, identities, next) {
   console.log('after __get__identities');
   next();
})
```

Comment: `GET /users/me/identities` should call `users.__get__identities(id, cb)` under the hood. Therefore `user.afterRemote('*.__get__identities', function(ctx, inst, next) { ... });` should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'prototype.__get__identities' to match the remote name if you like but as @IvanSchwarz has suggested, using '*.__get__identities' will also work.